# Why my @ApplicationScope CDI bean not updated?

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, cdi

In my application, I have an `@ApplicationScoped` CDI bean to store some information from the database:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class MrBean {
   @EJB
   private SoyaBean soyaBean;
   private List<Toys> myToys;

   @PostConstruct
   public void prepareMrBean() {
      this.myToys = soyaBean.getToys();
   }

   public void updateToys() {
      this.myToys = soyaBean.getToys();
   }
}
```

I also have a AddToy.xhtml page which would simply add a toy to the database. The backing bean is as following:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MrsBean {
   @EJB
   private SoyaBean soyaBean;
   @Inject
   private MrBean mrBean;

   public void addToy() {
      this.soyaBean.addToy();
      this.mrBean.updateToys();
   }
}
```

Since there is a new toy added to the database, I wanted to update the list of toys in mrBean. However, even though mrsBean called `mrBean.updateToys()`, the list of toys in mrBean is not updated at all. I have another ViewToys.xhtml with a `@RequestScoped` backing bean to view the list of toys and I didn't see the list get updated.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on how to tackle this problem.

**UPDATE**: This is my SoyaBean implementation:

```
@Stateless
public class SoyaBeanImpl implements SoyaBean {
   @PersistenceContext()
   private EntityManager em;

   @Override
   public List<Toys> getToys() {
      Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT T from Toys T");
      return (List<Toys>) q.getResultList();
   }

   @Override
   public void addToy() {
      Toys newToy = new Toys();
      em.persist(newToy);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** I'd also really appreciate if someone could show me how I can achieve the same goal in any ways other than my troubling way.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: Your question is sound, but your example has a red herring: the both beans have the same name, which is illegal in this construct.

Comment: I have just realized it after I clicked submit =). I have already updated my question with the proper name. :P

Comment: Haha, `MrsBean` :) Well, I believe the problem is related to EJB transactions. What happens if you call `updateToys()` in a new subsequent HTTP request?

Comment: When I clicked the confirm button on my addToy.xhtml page, I saw that the code returned successful (I have a `<p:message>` component to report the status). No exception occurred. My `getToys()` function in the `soyaBean` simply get all the rows from the Toy table. I'm really not sure what you mean by "subsequent HTTP request" though :P

Comment: @BalusC: I added a line `System.out.println(myToys.size());` in both the `prepareMrBean()` and the `updateToys()` functions. What I saw is the same number. I opened the database and the new toy was there. Do you have any ideas why my stateless bean couldn't detect the new entry?

Comment: Is it possible that CDI and EJB are executed in different transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the results of all SQL queries were cached. Hence, even though I tried to refresh the list of toys, it only received the old result. I solved this problem by setting the option `Shared Cache Mode` in the file `persistence.xml` to `None`.

I believe not using cache at all is not a good option. Hence, I'd be very grateful if someone could show me how I can achieve the same result without having to turn off cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no major technical errors in your code, these errors are usually related to, as you have implied, the state of the data being returned by Entity manger.

**Cluprit : The database?**

Of course, you could have a cacheing issue in the underlying db. However, this is unlikely given your description of the system.out statements.

**Culprit : The bean ?**

The more likely culprit is that the query results are somehow being cached in the bean, or rather, in the query result set return value.  If your test database allows dirty reads,  that could be an explanation.  This can be inspected by, for example, using an @Interceptor to refresh the query before any calls to getToys().

**Another potential pitfall here : mistaking statelessness vs caching.**

Finally : a brief word on statelessness.  Although you are right that the stateless of the bean should result, generally speaking , in data which is not stale -- this is not always the case.  The real definition of stateless beans in the EJB context is that those beans arent gauranteed to  have state over the course of the application lifecycle.

In summary there are 3 different ways to get to the bottom of your issue :

1) Make sure the database isn't doing anything funny with dirty reads.
2) Test to see if intercepting the call to getToys(), and running / verifying the database query has no issues
3) Make sure that the type of statelessness that you want is actually being implemented by your ejb container.

Comment: In my application, I also have a function for user to register for an account. After finish filling the form and submit, my activate account function can recognize the new account entry. I'm not really sure why I run into problem with creating new toys. I will try to check what you have recommended.

Comment: Hmmm.... I wonder... If you switch "getToys" to return the results of a new account... In the same method... Then does the get toys method work?  I know it sounds like a funny test but it would be insightful to know.

Comment: Sry for not answering your question. I have been trying to investigate the problem further and I found the solution =).