# why not refresh jsf page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I create a bean as

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class KhachHangMB implements Serializable {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "XoSoWebPU")
private EntityManager em;
private List<KhachHang> l;

public KhachHangMB() {
    l = new ArrayList<KhachHang>();
}
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    l = new ArrayList<KhachHang>();
    l = em.createNamedQuery("KhachHang.findAll").getResultList();
    MsgShow.showMsg("", "Init " + Math.random());
}

public List<KhachHang> retriveAllKhachHang() {
    return l;
}
```

}

And my jsf page:

```
<h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
            <h:dataTable value="#{khachHangMB.retriveAllKhachHang()}" var="item">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Idkh"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.idkh}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="TenKH"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.tenKH}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Cmnd"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.cmnd}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="DiaChi"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.diaChi}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="SoDT"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.soDT}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.email}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MaDuThuong"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.maDuThuong}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="GhiChu"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.ghiChu}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="MatKhau"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.matKhau}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:commandLink value="Click" action="home" />
        </h:form>
```

And my faces-config

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>trungthuong_list</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/f_trungthuong/trungthuong_list.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>home</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I click on command link the random was called but the data on page was not change although i have been edited data on database. Another case, i navigate to other page after that i return but the data is old (not using back of web browser, i'm using command link)! Please help me!

Comment: If your data has changed in database, you can restart the application just to make sure that its a JSF problem. As Mr.J4mes explains in his answer, it looks like a Hibernate problem. Another recommendation, you should separate the business logic from the view controller classes, this way your application will be easier to maintain and could have reusable assets (like one only method to retrieve the full list of `KhachHang` objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try setting the option `Shared Cache Mode` in the file `persistence.xml` to `None`. This helped me to solve a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376652/why-my-applicationscope-cdi-bean-not-updated) similar to yours some time ago. :)